# MMC crash in windows 10

Tags: certificate, windows-10, mmc, snap-in

On my Windows 10, mmc.exe crashes when I try to add the certificate snap-in. When I click "Ok" after having added the snap-in (computer account, local computer) the message: "Microsoft Management Console has stopped working" and I am offered a debug option.
There are no further error messages.
I have tried to run "sfc /scannow" and found nothing to repair.

Comment: Follow my [steps here](https://pastebin.com/YTaQwd8p) to let Wndows generate a crash dump. Zip the dmp and hare the dmp.

Comment: have you generated the crash dump?

Comment: @magicandre1981, the file is generated , How would i share the file to you ? what is the potential risk of sharing the dump file publicly. Can you provide your emailID (sorry if its against the rules of stackoverflow) to share the file ? Please advice .

Comment: upload the zip to OneDrive and create a text file with the DL link. Upload this text file with the DL link to my dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/request/gziMuJzaJxQrmIUokBC9 I don't have much space on my dropbox left, so don't try to upload the dump, only the txt with the link.

Comment: Its done, can you check it please .

Comment: ok, I posted what I saw from the dump

Answer (score 2):

The MMC is crashing because of the `SqlManager.dll` from SQLServer 2014 RTM (`2014.0120.2000.08 ((SQL14_RTM).140220-1924 )`)

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************


DUMP_CLASS: 2

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000072f3df90 rcx=000000000000000a
rdx=0000000072f3df90 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000080000010
rip=00007ffcb524a030 rsp=000000000f13ec18 rbp=000000001339d408
 r8=000000000f13eb78  r9=000000001339d408 r10=0000000000000000
r11=000000000f13ebe0 r12=0000000000220a5e r13=0000000000000090
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!RtlFailFast2:
00007ffc`b524a030 cd29            int     29h
Resetting default scope

FAULTING_IP: 
ntdll!RtlFailFast2+0
00007ffc`b524a030 cd29            int     29h

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 00007ffcb524a030 (ntdll!RtlFailFast2)
   ExceptionCode: c0000409 (Security check failure or stack buffer overrun)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 1
   Parameter[0]: 000000000000000a
Subcode: 0xa FAST_FAIL_GUARD_ICALL_CHECK_FAILURE

PROBLEM_CLASSES: 

    ID:     [0n262]
    Type:   [FAIL_FAST]
    Class:  Primary
    Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
            BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Add
    Data:   Omit
    PID:    [Unspecified]
    TID:    [Unspecified]
    Frame:  [0]

    ID:     [0n256]
    Type:   [GUARD_ICALL_CHECK_FAILURE]
    Class:  Addendum
    Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
            BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Add
    Data:   Omit
    PID:    [Unspecified]
    TID:    [Unspecified]
    Frame:  [0]

    ID:     [0n92]
    Type:   [AVRF]
    Class:  Addendum
    Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
            BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Add
    Data:   Omit
    PID:    [0x3be8]
    TID:    [0x3cf0]
    Frame:  [0] : ntdll!RtlFailFast2

BUGCHECK_STR:  FAIL_FAST_GUARD_ICALL_CHECK_FAILURE_AVRF

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  FAIL_FAST_GUARD_ICALL_CHECK_FAILURE_AVRF

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  FAIL_FAST

STACK_TEXT:  
00 ntdll!RtlFailFast2
01 ntdll!RtlpHandleInvalidUserCallTarget
02 ntdll!LdrpHandleInvalidUserCallTarget
03 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow
04 user32!DispatchClientMessage
05 user32!_fnDWORD
06 ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcherContinue
07 win32u!NtUserDestroyWindow
08 SqlManager_72c70000!CEventRegWnd::~CEventRegWnd
09 SqlManager_72c70000!CRT_INIT
0a SqlManager_72c70000!CRT_INIT
0b verifier!AVrfpStandardDllEntryPointRoutine
0c ntdll!LdrpCallInitRoutine
0d ntdll!LdrpProcessDetachNode
0e ntdll!LdrpUnloadNode
0f ntdll!LdrpDecrementModuleLoadCountEx
10 ntdll!LdrUnloadDll
11 KERNELBASE!FreeLibrary
12 combase!CClassCache::CDllPathEntry::CFinishObject::Finish
13 combase!CClassCache::CFinishComposite::Finish
14 combase!CClassCache::CleanUpDllsForApartment
15 combase!CCCleanUpDllsForApartment
16 combase!FinishShutdown::__l2::<lambda_ac39365968346bea08de70a73a47183a>::operator()
17 combase!ObjectMethodExceptionHandlingAction<<lambda_ac39365968346bea08de70a73a47183a> >
18 combase!FinishShutdown
19 combase!ApartmentUninitialize
1a combase!wCoUninitialize
1b combase!CoUninitialize
1c verifier!AVrfpCoUninitialize
1d mmcndmgr!MMC21ADDREMOVEUI::CAboutInfoThread::ThreadProc
1e msvcrt!_callthreadstartex
1f msvcrt!_threadstartex
20 verifier!AVrfpStandardThreadFunction
21 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk
22 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart
```

So update the SQL Server to [latest Service Pack](https://support.microsoft.com/en-US/kb/2958069) and Update Hotfix Rollup. Import the [uninstall .reg to disable dump creation and app verifier](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dyqg9jdlcztfbo5/WER_MMC_full_uninstall.reg).

Comment: thank you . am updating the latest Service Pack and try with it.

Comment: Still i have same problem, even after updating and restarting the machine.

Comment: create a new dump and share the link to me

Comment: its shared, can you check it

Comment: still same file version. looks like this DLL was not updated via SP2.

Comment: i have downloaded the Service pack from the link , and updated and restarted the machine. IS there any other way to manually ?

Comment: maybe the SP doesn't update the file. MS closed that paged where it listed compatible software. maybe SQL Server 2014 is not compatible

Comment: Now i try again, getting the following error.

https://1drv.ms/i/s!AhM8WW4ho4wBgcQb4wXfCnWWXN8Mug

Comment: good question. I don't use SQL server, so I can't answer this.

Comment: Its Ok, Thank you for the support. I have posted both for SQL error as well on MMC, 
Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43703500/sql-server-2014-error-on-updating-the-service-pack

Comment: Can confirm that it's SQL Server 2014, I had it installed for SSMS. After uninstalling SQL Server 2014, the certificates snapin for MMC worked again.