# SQL Server 2014 error on updating the service pack

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, mmc, servicepacks

I was using SQL Server 2014, and due to an error while adding a certificate in MMC, I have was told to update SQL Server.

Please see my link of post on MMC:

([MMC crash in windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43585564/mmc-crash-in-windows-10/43693097?noredirect=1#comment74451520_43693097))

Now I am getting the following error.

[image]

Can anyone advice me the further steps to proceed?

Comment: What version do you have now? What are you trying to update it with? Did you look at the bottom of the setup page like the picture tells you to do?

Comment: @James, 
I have SQL Server 2014,
My `@@Version` result is below,
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-GDR) (KB3194714) - 12.0.5203.0 (X64) 
 Sep 23 2016 18:13:56 
  Business Intelligence Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 15063: ) (Hypervisor)

After this issue, i have also installed Sql server 2016,  now i have both the instances running ,
which is ,  Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR) (KB3210089) - 13.0.4202.2 (X64) 
 Dec 13 2016 05:22:44 
 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 6.3 <X64> (Build 15063: ) (Hypervisor)